# I printed my PhD thesis and one of the image graphics came out as a black square and I sent copies yesterday to the reviewrs

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

I don't understand how this happened I sent the printing service a pdf. And in the pdf the image is completely normal.

And two other graphics lost their labels. I don't know how this happened.

Will this be looked down upon?

Comment: Is it a png with a transparent background? The same thing happened to me once with that type of image (turning into a black square when printed).

Comment: @astronat I don't know what type of file it is, because one is a screenshot and the other ones are graphic plots I made in Origin just like the rest of the graphs in my thesis, only these two have lost their labels.

Comment: This is unclear because print versions are unlikely to be viewed by anyone.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You think? I got an impression that physical copies are more preffered.

Answer (score 2):

These things can happen with printing services. This is why you always get a test print, which you check thoroughly. You did get that, right? And you did check it, right? If so, then you probably have a good case against the printing service, to get them to print replacement copies free of charge.

But this does not help you right now. Yes, it will be an issue for the committee if several figures in your thesis are not legible. What you can do is to write an email to your committee members explaining the situation. Attach a pdf of your thesis - which you have double checked to be correct - and promise to send them replacement copies once they arrive.

And before you send the replacement copies, you make damn sure that all the graphics display as it should.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that the next time. There is one figure that is just a black square and two figures that lost their labels. I have like 65 of them. I hope it won't be a big deal. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I add that for practical purpose you can send just the pages where errors occurred. They can easily print them and insert them in the book. Most likely they will use a hard copy for reviewing, and as such it will be faster and easy. A kind of EC like in "professional" books. @marietiara

Comment: @Alchimista I managed to stop the recommended mail, luckily it didn't leave the lab yet. I will make new copies.